# Deconstructed parameters as a dictionary inside function

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a function as follows:

```
function myfunction(a,{b=1,c=2}={}){
 //... want to get the values b,c,... as k:v dict
}
```

Is there any way to get the complete map of parameters inside the deconstructed dictionary, as a dictionary object inside the function? Effectively I want to be able to access the family of arguments beyond the 1st positional argument to store in memory, as if I were accessing it via `arguments[1]`

Comment: Did you try accessing it via arguments? What happened?

Comment: I did, it only supplies the values which are overriden from the default provided as part of the function delcaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `arguments[1]` will return undefined if you call `myfunction(1)` the only approach I can think of is to hold off on destructuring until the first line of the function.

```js
function myfunction(a, params = {}){
 const { b = 1, c = 2 } = params;
 const paramsWithDefaults = { b, c, ...params };
 // JSON.stringify so the output is single line
 console.log(JSON.stringify(paramsWithDefaults));
}

myfunction(1);
myfunction(1, { b: 55 });
myfunction(1, { b: 55, c: 66 });
myfunction(1, { d: 77 });
```

EDIT: If we need the defaults to be in the function signature, for some reason (IDE support, for example), then this might do the trick, though it becomes a bit harder to understand at a glance:

```js
function myfunction(a, { b = 1, c = 2 } = {}){
 const params = arguments[1] || {}
 const paramsWithDefaults = { b, c, ...params };
 // JSON.stringify so the output is single line
 console.log(JSON.stringify(paramsWithDefaults));
}

myfunction(1);
myfunction(1, { b: 55 });
myfunction(1, { b: 55, c: 66 });
myfunction(1, { d: 77 });
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Well this approach certainly achieves the mechanics of what I want, the obvious downside is that the default arguments and the 'signature' of the params dictionary then obfuscates any intelligent IDE environments ability to prompt the developer about what the argument expects.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a snippet where the defaults are kept in the function signature, and corrected a bug in the original snippet.